# How can you cancel a SQL Server execution process programmatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say you have execute the following (long running) process from your code:

```
int processID = DB.Execute(SQL); //some long running sql statement
```

Is there a way to programatically call SQL Server to cancel the process if it is taking too long (kind of like hitting the "Stop" button in QueryAnalyzer)?

```
//cancel the process if it is taking too long
DB.Execute("sp_CancelProcess @ProcessID=" + processID);
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to your tag choices - tags are how you connect your question to the appropriate audience.

Answer (score 8):

use [`KILL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) with the process id:

```
KILL 53;
```

Just be aware that you can't kill your own spid, you need to create another connection and then kill the spid from the

if you try to kill your own SPID you will get the following error

```
Server: Msg 6104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot use KILL to kill your own process.
```

Answer (score 4):

[Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) @Spid

note that this is a last effort. you should just close the connection on the client to kill the process.

Comment: Just be aware that you can't kill your own spid, you need to create another connection and then kill the spid from the

Answer (score 2):

```
sp_who2
```

List of process displays

```
Find you SPID 

Kill SPID
```

If error message you can't kill your own process

See where the process rund in your management studio and stop it.

Or close current connection and reopen and try to kill now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your query asynchronously, as follows:

```
    SqlConnection _anotherConnection;
    SqlCommand _anotherCommand;
    IAsyncResult _anotherCommandStarted;
    _anotherCommand = _anotherConnection.CreateCommand();
    _anotherCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH; BEGIN TRANSACTION; {0};", hookCommand);
    _anotherCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    _anotherCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    _anotherCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Data.Hook1 SET i=1-i";
    _anotherCommandStarted = _anotherCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
```

To cancel the command, run this:

```
    _anotherCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery(_anotherCommandStarted);
```

Comment: The BeginExecuteNonQuery() suggestion is good, but EndExecuteNonQuery does not cancel the command - it blocks until the command completes.