# Unable to drop table on Sql Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm unable to drop a table on Sql Azure. Previously I cancelled a query that involves this table, because takes to long on execute. Maybe other procedure is blocking me.

How can I solve this problem on Sql Azure?

Thanks.

Comment: What message do you get when try to drop the table?

Comment: Maybe the query was still executing when you tried to drop the table, even though you cancelled it on the client. As Igor said, post the full conversation (your command and the reply you got).

Comment: I got an execution time expired error. I was able to drop the table after one day.

Comment: But I still dont know how to force close current connection on Sql Azure, so the question is open.

Comment: To terminate an executing process you can use the Kill statement as answered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1092567/376366

Answer (score 0):

Try Restarting and Apply:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [tablename]) DROP TABLE [tablename]
```